# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I got an crash from my real user who's system is android Lollipop,I don't have any webviews in my app,it is just a videoplayer.Is it the rendering problem?

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nDeleteProxy(Native Method)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize(ThreadedRenderer.java:407)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:194)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:177)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and thread running info :

## main(1):

```
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native Method)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:342)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2751)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2584)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2176)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6643)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

## ReferenceQueueDaemon(2201):

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:137)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
#FinalizerDaemon(2202):
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nDeleteProxy(Native Method)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.finalize(ThreadedRenderer.java:407)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:194)
java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:177)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
#HeapTrimmerDaemon(2204):
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:314)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

## GCDaemon(2205):

```
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.waitForConcurrentGCRequest(Native Method)
java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run(Daemons.java:334)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't know how to find out the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at how to ask a question using a [minimal, complete, verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)